# CSS Animation works on Android WebView but not on iOS WebView

Tags: html, css, uiwebview

My animation is not working on iOS WebView. I created a box which has a `@keyframes` animation. It is working in Android WebView but not in iOS.

```css
.slidRtoLanim {
  transform: translateX(30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
}

.slidRtoLanim.actv {
  animation: RLslid 0.1s forwards
}

@keyframes RLslid {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes RLslid {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slidRtoLanim actv"></div>
```

Comment: did you fix it ?

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) or [How to create Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212). Is there a reason you’re not using `from` blocks in your `@keyframes`?

Comment: consider -webkit-animation too ?

Comment: I removed the "visibility: hidden" CSS and its work, I don't understand how but it's working and thank u friends